# C++ simple but tricky recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

Simple enough, I am trying to define a recursive method to return the medium of a vector. However, my code didn't work, the compiler doesn't complain anything but the program just terminated at the point when the function was called. I tried to look through the code again and again. Any help would be greatly appreciated :D

```
int minR(vector<int> vec, size_t start){
  if(start == vec.size()-1){return vec[start];}
  int temp = minR(vec, start++);
  return ((vec[start] < temp) ? vec[start] : temp);
}
```

Comment: I didnt call the debugger, I will try to do it now, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It It's "minimum" actually if you read the code :)

Comment: "I didnt call the debugger" - I'd make that your first port of call next time - it's an important skill for a programmer

Comment: When learning recursion, it's important to work out small examples **on paper**, then use the debugger (or diagnostic output messages) to make sure your code does what you've already figured out on paper.

Comment: A performance suggestion: you are passing the `vec` parameter _by value_ and creating many unneeded copies of the vector. You should instead pass by _const reference_ by saying `const vector<int> &vec`

Answer (score 2):

In this line

```
int temp = minR(vec, start++);
```

You are calling `minR(vec, start)` and not `minR(vec, start+1)` as you think you are. This causes an infinite recursion and that's why your program stops.

You should call

```
int temp = minR(vec, start + 1);
```

Comment: Wow, unbelievable, u'r great, I tried with different implementations for all of the night and all didnt work. I thought they are the same. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: @user1534664 because that changes anything? ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
 int temp = minR(vec, start++);
```

should be this:

```
 int temp = minR(vec, start + 1);
```

The postfix `++` increments the value and "returns" the previous value, which is essentially calling the function with the same value of `start`.